# using manifest or just updating cache?

Tags: html, caching

I was reading about cache cleaning and update for my website, and i just can't figure it out what is the diffence in using a manifest or this function below:

```
// Check if a new cache is available on page load.
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {

  window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', function(e) {
    if (window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY) {
      // Browser downloaded a new app cache.
      if (confirm('A new version of this site is available. Load it?')) {
        window.location.reload();
      }
    } else {
      // Manifest didn't changed. Nothing new to server.
    }
  }, false);

}, false);
```

link: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Comment: The manifest file and the function above are two separate things that work together. The manifest says what files to cache and what files to load when accessed offline. The function above refreshes the page for the user so the user is using the updated version of the site on that visit instead of on future visits. An updated (changed) manifest file will trigger the function above.

Comment: @hungerstar but without the manifest this function still works, isn't it?

Comment: How would the `updateready` event be fired if a new manifest file is present? But I guess this conversation is a bit moot anyways as [_Application Cache_ has been depreciated in favor of _Service Workers_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache).

Comment: I will have a look at the link, Thanks! ;)